# How can i include file of styles for only one template?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I have a Materialize.min.css link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
```

And i need to include this file only in one template of Vue, because it damages other files.
Is it possible to do?

Comment: maybe reading [this article](https://medium.com/@renatello/load-external-css-file-into-vue-js-component-e61673753a2b) could help you

Comment: @hamid-davodi thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Copy all of the content from this URL `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css` and create a new `css` file then past the copied contents on your project.

```
 mounted() {
    const plugin = document.getElementById("__ID_OF_YOUR_SELECTED_ELEMENT__");
    plugin.setAttribute(
      "href",
      "__PATH_OF_YOUT_CSS__"
    );
    plugin.async = true;
    document.head.appendChild(plugin);
  }
```

will apply only the element you had selected